# How to get number of pending requests or accept requests without blocking in ServerSocket?

Tags: java, serversocket

I created subclass of `java.net.ServerSocket`.

In `run` method I want to get all pending requests and send them error message.

How to do it with `ServerSocket`?

Here is my code:

```
public class SafeWalkServer extends ServerSocket implements Runnable {

    public SafeWalkServer(int port) throws IOException {
        super(port);

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            boolean isShutdown = false;
            while (!isShutdown) {
                Socket client = accept();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());

                if (clientText.startsWith(":RESET"))
**//at this point I need to send error message to all pending requests.**
                        Socket sock = accept(); 
}
}
}
}
```

I need either number of pending requests or non-blocking variant of `accept`?

Comment: Why? What good is it going to do you? You should process accepts as fast as possible so there are always zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do non-blocking sockets with [ServerSocketChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ServerSocketChannel.html).  call [configureBlocking(false)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/spi/AbstractSelectableChannel.html#configureBlocking-boolean-) to do non-blocking.  There are many good tutorials (with sample code) like [The Rox Java NIO Tutorial](http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/).

Comment: The ROX NIO tutorial is garbage. Guy doesn't even know that closing the channel cancels the key, and he invents a lot of non-existent difficulties about other things as well.